# C# get selected IGridDataRow value Desktop app

Tags: c#, winforms

In my WindowsForms project, I have a class with CellEditor (IGridDataRow row), I want to take the value of the selected item and pass it to another class.

```
namespace Projects.test.Gui
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class testAttribute : Attribute, IEditorAttribute
    {
        public CellEditor GetEditor(IGridDataRow row)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> Names = new List<string>();
                Helper Helper = new Helper();
                Namesdata[] mNames = Helper.FindAllNames();

                if (mNames != null)
                {
                    Names = mNames.Select(mName => mName.Name).ToList();
                }

                return new ButtonEditor(Names);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogService.LogError(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your project UI using WindowsForms or WindowPresentationForms (WPF)?

Comment: It's windowsForms

Comment: Could you please remove the try-catch block and give us a read at the exception? (the full exception with call stack, yada yada teh way VS presents it to you)

Comment: What? give me the link to freelancer thingy